# How to persistently save Kafka Connect configuration files?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I encountered an issue with Kafka Connect. I am using HTTP to create configuration files, but after restarting, these configuration files are lost. How can I make these configuration files persistently saved?

I want to save the configuration files created via HTTP.

Answer (score 0):

> after restarting, these configuration files are lost

Kafka  defaults to store topic data in /tmp folder

Kafka Connect stores data in a topic.

Therefore, you need to move your Kafka `logs.dir` config.

Otherwise, you should pre-save your connector configs as files before you upload to Connect, or use other tools like Terraform or Strimzi Operator for Connect

Comment: Thank you. I have already configured Kafka Connect using a local file instead of an HTTP request.

Comment: Okay, so I don't understand the question then. You cannot create configuration files from HTTP. You need to create before sending. And if you're already creating them, then they're already saved